# Help with a definition of a two-person game in a referenced paper

Tags: game-theory, machine-learning, nash-equilibrium

In the paper ["Finding Mixed Nash Equilibria of Generative Adversarial Networks"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.02002) the authors write in equation (1) on page 2:

> Consider the classical formulation of a two-player game with
>   *finitely* many strategies:
>   \begin{equation*}
> \tag1\label1
> \min_{\boldsymbol{p} \in \Delta_m} \max_{\boldsymbol{q} \in \Delta_n} \langle \boldsymbol{q},\boldsymbol{a} \rangle -
> \langle \boldsymbol{q},A\boldsymbol{p} \rangle ,
> \end{equation*}
>   where $A$ is a payoff matrix, $\boldsymbol a$ is a vector, and $ \Delta_d :=
> \{\boldsymbol{z} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^d \mid \sum\nolimits_{i=1}^d z_i = 1\}$ is
>   the probability simplex, representing the *mixed strategies* (i.e.,
>   probability distributions) over $d$ pure strategies. A pair
>   $(\boldsymbol{p}_{\text{NE}},\boldsymbol{q}_{\text{NE}})$ achieving the min-max
>   value in (\ref{1}) is called a mixed NE.

I was wondering:

- What does this formulation mean?
- The formulation seems to result in a **parametrized** by a vector $\boldsymbol a$ pair of strategies $(\boldsymbol p, \boldsymbol q)$. What is the role of vector $\boldsymbol a$ in the above equation?

Thank you

After further contemplating: I guess they want to align their application (GAN) with the game theory framework. To that end, they write on page 3:

> [W]e consider the set of all probability distributions
>   over $\Theta$ and $\mathcal{W}$, and we search for the optimal distribution that solves the following program:
>   \begin{equation*}
> \tag4\label4
> \min_{\nu \in \mathcal{M}(\Theta)} \max_{\mu \in \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{W})}
> \mathbb{E}_{\boldsymbol{w} \sim \mu} \mathbb{E}_{X \sim \mathbb{P}_{real}} [f_\boldsymbol{w}(X)] - 
> \mathbb{E}_{\boldsymbol{w} \sim \mu} \mathbb{E}_{\boldsymbol{\theta} \sim \nu} \mathbb{E}_{X \sim \mathbb{P}_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}} [f_\boldsymbol{w}(X)] . 
> \end{equation*}

They then show that the above can be cast as

> \begin{equation*}
> \tag5\label5
> \min_{\nu \in \mathcal{M}(\Theta)} \max_{\mu \in \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{W})} \langle \mu,g \rangle -
> \langle \mu,G\nu \rangle ,
> \end{equation*}
>   with $g$ defined as $g : \mathcal{W} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(w) := \mathbb{E}_{X \sim \mathbb{P}_{real}} [f_\boldsymbol{w}(X)]$, the operator $G : \mathcal{M}(\Theta) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{W})$ as $(G\nu)(w) := \mathbb{E}_{\boldsymbol{\theta} \sim \nu} \mathbb{E}_{X \sim \mathbb{P}_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}} [f_\boldsymbol{w}(X)]$ and denoting $\langle \mu,h \rangle := \mathbb{E}_{\mu}h$ for any probability
>   measure $\mu$ and function $h$ (where $\langle \mu,h \rangle$ is NOT an inner product, but a dual pairing in Banach spaces),

which looks like (\ref{1}) (for *finitely* many strategies). Notice that (\ref{4}) has a free parameter $\mathbb{P}_{real}$ (hidden in $g$ in (\ref{5})), which $\boldsymbol{a}$ in (\ref{1}) seems to have been introduced to account for.

Also, 
\begin{equation*}
\min_{\boldsymbol{p} \in \Delta_m} \max_{\boldsymbol{q} \in \Delta_n} \langle \boldsymbol{q},\boldsymbol{a} \rangle -
\langle \boldsymbol{q},A\boldsymbol{p} \rangle = 
\min_{\boldsymbol{p} \in \Delta_m} \max_{\boldsymbol{q} \in \Delta_n} \langle \boldsymbol{q}, (\boldsymbol{a} \otimes \boldsymbol{1} - A)\boldsymbol{p} \rangle
\end{equation*}

This is because $\boldsymbol{p}$ is a probability simplex and therefore each row $m$ of vector $\boldsymbol{a}$ increases row $m$ of payoff matrix $A$. Therefore, the above game is equivalent to a standard zero-sum game with payoff matrix $\tilde{A}=(\boldsymbol{a} \otimes \boldsymbol{1} - A)$.

Comment: Please be consistent with typography:  if you use $\boldsymbol a$ `$\boldsymbol a$` once, don't switch to ***a*** `***a***`for the same variable later.  I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The classical formulation of a two player zero sum game with finitely many strategies is $\langle q, Ap \rangle$. There is no need to introduce the vector $a$, as it can be incorporated in the matrix $A$. In the paper you mention, the authors assume that it is too costly to evaluate $A$; maybe the formulation they provide is useful in their analysis.

Comment: Is $A$ assumed non-singular?  If not, why can $a$ be incorporated into it?

Answer (score 0):

This **non-standard** formulation matches better the intended application - (Wasserstein) GAN. It can be mapped to the **standard** formulation $\langle \boldsymbol{q}, \tilde{A}\boldsymbol{p} \rangle$ through a new payoff matrix $\tilde{A} = \boldsymbol{a} \otimes \boldsymbol{1} - A$, where $\otimes$ is the outer product operation ($\boldsymbol{a} \otimes \boldsymbol{b} = \boldsymbol{a} \boldsymbol{b}^T)$